# React Native JavaScript another screen is visible on top of the current screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, bottomtabs

Any help will be appreciated.
I am using Expo React-Native with JavaScript and I have tried to create a bottom-button-bar for my app, but it causes my desired screen to present on top of my Home screen like that:

[image]

In this picture, the Orders screen takes the bottom of the screen while the home screen is still visible, even though I pressed the Orders button.
I am not sure what is causing this issue.
This is the related code of my home screen:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import colors from '../colors';
import { AntDesign, Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import ProductsList from "../components/ProductsList";
import { listenForProducts } from "../products";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Orders from "./Orders";


const Home = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = listenForProducts((products) => {
            setProducts(products);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-gray-200">
                    <ProductsList products={products} />
                    <StatusBar style={"dark"} />
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
            <Tab.Navigator tabBar={CustomTabBar}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </View>
    );
};

const CustomTabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation }) => {
    const getTabBarIcon = (name, focused) => {
        switch (name) {
            case "Profile":
                return <AntDesign name="profile" size={24} color={focused ? colors.primary : colors.gray} />;
            case "Orders":
                return <Feather name="shopping-bag" size={24} color={focused ? colors.primary : colors.gray} />;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.tabBar}>
            {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
                const label = options.title !== undefined ? options.title : route.name;
                const isFocused = state.index === index;

                const onPress = () => {
                    const event = navigation.emit({
                        type: 'tabPress',
                        target: route.key,
                        canPreventDefault: true,
                    });

                    if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                        navigation.navigate(route.name);
                    }
                };

                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={route.key}
                        accessibilityRole="button"
                        accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
                        accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
                        testID={options.tabBarTestID}
                        onPress={onPress}
                        style={styles.tabBarButton}
                    >
                        {getTabBarIcon(label, isFocused)}
                        <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? colors.primary : colors.gray }}>
                            {label}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            })}
        </View>
    );
};

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5",
    },
    tabBar: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: colors.gray,
    },
    tabBarButton: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using createBottomTabNavigator as a navigator.
This code fixed the issue:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import colors from '../colors';
import { AntDesign, Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import ProductsList from "../components/ProductsList";
import { listenForProducts } from "../products";


const Home = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = listenForProducts((products) => {
      setProducts(products);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-gray-200">
          <ProductsList products={products} />
          <StatusBar style={"dark"} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.tabBar}>
        <TabBarButton
          label="Profile"
          icon={<AntDesign name="profile" size={24} color={colors.primary} />}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}
        />
        <TabBarButton
          label="Orders"
          icon={<Feather name="shopping-bag" size={24} color={colors.primary} />}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Orders")}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const TabBarButton = ({ onPress, label, icon }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.tabBarButton}>
    {icon}
    <Text style={styles.tabBarLabel}>{label}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5",
  },
  tabBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: colors.gray,
  },
  tabBarButton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  tabBarLabel: {
    color: colors.primary,
  },
});
```